# How to call static function defined in variable?

Tags: php

I'm writing my own MVC framework, and i need to call static function
I have routing defined in ini file like this

```
[someAction]
route[] = /someroute
layout = layoutname
action[] = someAction@SomeController
```

after matching routing im using explode() function to split action and controller

```
$action = explode('@', $this->_action); 
//$this->_action = someAction@SomeController
```

and now I wanna call

```
$action[1]::$action[0]();
```

But php thinks that I wanna call static field instead of method, can somebody tell me how to call it as method ?

Comment: Use `call_user_func()`

Comment: Possibly something like `$a = new $action[1](); $a->$action[0]();`

Comment: Have a look at `forward_static_call` http://php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call.php or `call_user_func` http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php
I'm sure you'd find your answer in any one of these functions.

Comment: Easier would be to switch the "controller" and the "action" so you can just call `$action()` https://eval.in/181257

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func()`

Try this :

```
call_user_func(array($action[1],$action[0]));
```

edit : depending of your PHP version, PeeHaa's comment is a good idea !

Answer (score 0):

You can call it this way:

```
<?php

    list($action, $controller) = explode('@', $this->_action);
    $controller::$action();

?>
```